# Array instantiating

Tags: java, arrays, tiles

I have a tile object which I named `bt`, as well as other tiles like a grass tile, gt, and a flower tile, ft. These are all objects.

I then put the names of those objects in to an array to create a map that renders to the screen. like so:

```
Tile[] map = new Map{bt, bt, bt, bt,
                     gt, gt, gt, gt,
                     bt, bt, ft, ft}
```

Now my question is, am I referencing a name to the tile objects? meaning, is there actually only the three tiles, not the 12 as outlined? If so, how can I go around that? My goal is to make 1 of each different tile, and then have the array repeat them, basically instantiating a new tile each time.

Comment: Are you **sure** you're working in Java?  The code you've posted does not look like any legal Java I've ever seen.

Comment: I am working in java, I just put that up because I didn't have the code in front of me and I knew people would understand what I meant. Was I wrong? Originally the map actually gets in a tile[] and a few other parameters to make the map. And I know I do use curly braces to define specific indexes in the array at array instanciation.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask], and you'll have a much easier and more productive time here.

Comment: @TravisDewitt I think your use of `Map` is confusing because it is an important class in Java that has nothing to do with your question.  Using that _plus_ the incorrect java syntax made me think you were confusing it with a different language.

Comment: Would it help to know I didn't know there was a very helpful class in java called map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't going to compile I'm afraid.

But given that your question is

> Now my question is, am I referencing a name to the tile objects? meaning, is there actually only the three tiles, not the 12 as outlined?

When you create an array of type `Tile`, you're declaring a block of *pointers to Tile objects*, but not the `Tile` objects themselves. The idea is that you go through and populate them yourself. When you create a `Tile[]` object like so:

```
Tile[] tiles = new Tile[10];
```

You've got an array that looks like this:

```
tiles[0] = null;
tiles[1] = null;
...
tiles[9] = null;
```

Then, you go through and populate them..

```
tiles[2] = new Tile();
```

And now the array looks like:

```
tiles[0] = null;
tiles[1] = null;
tiles[2] = Tile[Some Hex Code here]
tiles[3] = null;
...
tiles[9] = null;
```

So to answer your original question, if you were to go through and manually *instanciate* 12 `Tile` objects, then there will be `12` pointers to `12` different `Tile` objects held in your array.

Comment: Thats very helpful indeed, thank you. I'll go see if I can fix my issue with this new knowledge.

Comment: Wanted to let you know you helped me solve my problem with this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over your tiles and make a new one for each...

```
Tile[] map = new Tile[] {bt, bt, bt, bt, gt, gt, gt, gt, bt, bt, ft, ft};
ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();
for (Tile tile : map) {
    tiles.add(new Tile(tile.text));
}
map = tiles.toArray(map);
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I use this, I get the same result, minus the animating lol. When I access tile 10, I still only get the first tile.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a abstract tile class and create the array with that abstract tile class, 
then apply some looping and instantiate the objects with the child objects namely
you want namly bt gt and ft

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution you are looking for is

```
Tile[] map = new Tile[12]();//declare a tile array that can hold 12 Tile Reference



//Assign those 12 references to the Objects  


for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
map[i]=bt;
}

for(int i=4;i<8;i++)
{
map[i]=gt;
}

for(int i=8;i<10;i++)
{
map[i]=bt;
}
for(int i=10;i<12;i++)
{
map[i]=ft;
}
```

Comment: Tile[] map = { bt, bt, bt, bt, gt, gt, gt, gt, bt, bt, bt, bt, ft, ft, ft, ft } Is the same thing as you defined above. This doesn't work for me, I need to find a way to instantiate them in the map.

Comment: Are the tiles already created if not add this to the loops , map[i]=new Tile()